# Google Analytics code always reports page name as being "$A"

Tags: google-analytics

I have some code (below) that I'm using to track pageviews on Google Analytics.  In Google Analytics, all pages end up having the name "$A".

I can't seem to find anyone who has had the same issue and I can't see what I'm doing wrong:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();


    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

</script>

<script src="/__utm.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: The Urchin Tracking Module.  The site is transitioning away from using Urchin and is now using GA.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Urchin since it's been years since I used it, but is it possible that Urchin is interfering with GA? I would try removing it, at least on some test page and see what happens.

Comment: Good Suggestion; but I've tried removing it [and waited for the report to update] but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I tried replacing the _trackPageview line is something like this:  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', window.location.pathname]); - but the page name still shows us as $A

Comment: You shouldn't need `window.location.pathname`. Just `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview'])` should be sufficient.

Comment: Also consider changing `/ga.js` to `/u/ga_debug.js` to get the debug version which logs messages to the console with what it's doing.

Comment: Thank you Michael for your debug suggestion.  However it doesn't seem to give me any more information.  I got the following:  _gaq.push processing : "[_setAccount,UA-6983493-2]"\n
_gaq.push processing : "[_trackPageview]"\n
Track Pageview

Comment: ... which appears to be correct; but every page on my website has the name $A. (instead of the path/page name).  On reports that show page title; I can see the proper page title.  But otherwise all pages show as $A

Comment: Do you have a live page exhibiting this behaviour you could point to?

Comment: Yes.  I have created the following page trying to diagnose the issue.  I thought my problem may have to do with some sort of conflict with another JS file; so I have stripped nearly everything from the page that doesn't NEED to be there.  The page is using /u/ga_debug.js (as per Michael's suggestion) and GA appears to be working - but when I refer to my GA content overview report, all page requests were for pages with the name $A still.  http://ads-pipe.com/en/product.ga.asp?page=Pipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like, rather than there being a problem with the tracking code, that the problem is actually with a filter configured for your account.

Specifically, $A makes it sound like you have an improperly configured Reyes based filter that, rather than outputting the regex match, is instead outputting the string "$A", which is meaningless unless you're properly using RegEx.

Can you post detailed information about the profile? In any case, you shouldn.t be filtering on a main profile, since filters cannot be undone, so any configuration errors on your main profile will result in permanently lost data.

My recommendation is to totally remove the filters in pladce, duplicate the profile and apply your desired filters against the duplicate, to mitigate potential data loss problems like this.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I found the filter in question and have removed it (a co-worker is going to get an ear full!).